# Firefox 2 and Firefox 3 on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, firefox, installation

I need both Firefox 2 and Firefox 3 on my Mac OS X for testing purposes.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

See if this approach could help solve your problem: [OS X install firefox 2 firefox 3 same computer](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2828/os_x_install_firefox_2_firefox_3_same_computer/)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the application name once it is installed.  So

- Open the firefox 2 dmg
- Copy Firefox to Applications
- Rename Firefox to Firefox2

Repeat for Firefox 3.  You can have as many versions as you need.
This should work for just about any application.  Just be careful with Apple apps that use the "Syetem Update".  If they are moved/renamed the updated may not find them.